# Execution path trouble with Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a setup where in one file (LoginDelegate) I have a function to check if a user exists:

```
class LogInDelegate {
    func userCheck(email: String, completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
        authUserCheck() {
            let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

            usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue("\(email)").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                if (snapshot.value is NSNull) { completion(false) }
                else { completion(true) }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

On my view controller I have some other functions to check changes on a couple of textFields, if the user have entered a valid e-mail and a long enough password, then this function executes:

```
self.forwardButton.enabled = true
delegate.userCheck(email) { userExists in
    if userExists {
        self.forwardButton.setTitle(buttonTitle.login.rawValue, forState: .Normal)
    } else {
        self.forwardButton.setTitle(buttonTitle.new.rawValue, forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

The first time the userCheck function is called, the .observeEventType closure is not executed. You have to make another change to the text field so that the userCheck is called a second time and just then the closure is executed.

Why it doesn't execute the first time? Is it because of the nested closures? If so, what can I do?

Comment: What is `authUserCheck()`?

Comment: You cannot access the list of users in the database without authenticating, so authUserCheck signs in to the database for making the check and after the check it signs out.

Comment: Do you want to check if the email already exists in the DB ?And if it does prompt the user about it.?

Comment: It automatically switches between login and register. So, yeah, sort of.

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem. In the authUserCheck, after signing in and executing the closure, it immediately signed out, so it didn't gave time for the network request to do its thing.

Comment: I suspected `authUserCheck` was messing something up. Glad you figured it out! :)